# Node webkit app debugging in WebStorm 11

Tags: webstorm, node-webkit

I am puzzled by the problem for 2 days. Any tips are appreciated.

A very simple node-webkit app is created: helloworld.

package.json:

```
{
    "main": "index.html",
    "name": "helloworld-demo",
   "node-main": "hello.js",
    "keywords": [ "demo", "node-webkit" ],
    "window": {
        "title": "node-webkit demo",
        "icon": "link.png",
        "toolbar": true,
        "frame": false,
        "width": 800,
        "height": 500,
        "position": "mouse",
        "min_width": 400,
        "min_height": 200,
        "max_width": 800,
        "max_height": 600
    },
    "webkit": {
        "plugin": true
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World! </title>
</head>
<body >
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
We are using node.js
</body>
</html>
```

WebStorm 11 settings as below:

[image: link to image "webstorm debugging settings"]

"run" is ok. The app runs normally.
When starting "debug":, the problem string is:

```
C:\Users\lizhen\Downloads\nwjs-v0.14.5-win-x64\nw.exe --remote-debugging-port=49368 --url=data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+PHRpdGxlPkxvYWRpbmcgZmlsZTovLy9DOiU1Q1VzZXJzJTVDbGl6aGVuJTVDRG93bmxvYWRzJTVDbm9kZWpzX3dlYmtpdFByYWN0aWNlJTVDaGVsbG93b3JkL2luZGV4Lmh0bWw8L3RpdGxlPg== C:\Users\lizhen\Downloads\nodejs_webkitPractice\helloword

Process finished with exit code -1
```

[image: link to image "problem capture"]

I looked into the JetBrains documentation and can't find what caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging doesn't work for NW 0.13+. Please follow [WEB-18588](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18588) for updates